# How to use Keycloak as IDP for MSAL

Tags: java, keycloak, msal

I have a webapp which authenticates users using Azure Entra ID over MSAL4J library. Now I need to replace Azure with Keycloak. I don't want to use any external IDP so Keycloak is the only IDP in my environment and I have created an identity provider in Keycloak which is Keycloak OpenID Connect. I have the following config for Azure:

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: 604***
    client-id: b4f***
    client-secret: S3o***
```

Is it possible to redirect MSAL to Keycloak server?
If possible, how can I do that and what do I need to change in my config file?